# How to get the CloudFront endpoint country of a client request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

My website is hosted in S3 and a CloudFront Distribution is pointing to it.

In my website I need to know from which country the request for my website comes from.

Is there a way for CloudFront to add this information based on the CloudFront endpoints location to the request, maybe as a header or so?

Comment: You asked about adding the information *"to the request,"* and that is the answer you got... but if your site is hosted on S3 behind CloudFront, then adding the information to the request will send it to S3, where it will be ignored.  I wonder whether you were thinking of adding it to the *response*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html

> If you want CloudFront to cache different versions of your objects based on the country that the request came from, **configure CloudFront to forward the CloudFront-Viewer-Country header to your origin**. CloudFront automatically converts the IP address that the request came from into a two-letter country code. For an easy-to-use list of country codes, sortable by code and by country name, see the Wikipedia entry ISO 3166-1 alpha-2.